# How do I see all services that a .NET IServiceProvider can provide?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a general question regarding .NET

I am given an instance of the [IServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, but I have little documentation as to what might be possible to get from it. How would I find out a list of all the services it might provide?

Comment: What do you mean you are given an `IServiceProvider`? Do you mean you have a class that implements `IServiceProvider`? What do you mean by "all the services it might provide"? Your question doesn't make much sense, and certainly isn't something that can be answered with so little information

Comment: @musefan I mean that I have been given an object that implements `IServiceProvider`, and since that objects provides services, I would like to see all the services it can provide. Services are retreived through the `.GetService(Type)` method

Comment: Since the default IServiceProvider seems not to have such functionality, it worth mentioning that DryIoC implementation of IServiceProvider does have this: IContainer.GetServiceRegistrations().

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This was originally written in 2015, and things have changed since then.  If this answer in still accepted as you're reading, see additional answers below.

---

[`System.IServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) has a single method, `.GetService(Type)`, which returns a single service.  It's essentially a map from types to services.  Critically to your question, it does *not* provide access to all keys, probably because it's intended for implementation over the wire.

It's up to the class *implementing* the interface to expose a method or property that allows discovery of the services it provides - **there is no general way to see all provided services using the interface alone.**

#### Solutions:

- If you have control over the service providers' source, make a child interface that allows what you want

  ```
    interface IBetterServiceProvider : System.IServiceProvider
       {
           IList<object> GetAllServices();
           IList<Type> GetAllServicedTypes();
       }
  ```

  and make your services implement it.
- If you *don't* have control over the service providers' source, either cast to the `IServiceProvider` implementation type, or use reflection to look for properties or methods that tell you what you want.  If there appears to be a consistent `.GetServices()` sort of method in the providers you're working with, then you can use dynamic dispatch <sup>[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), [2](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/17/where-do-you-benefit-from-dynamic-typing/), [3](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter14/DynamicGotchas.aspx)</sup> to access that method without casting.

---

That said, even Microsoft's own implementations of the class are a bit of a rabbit hole.  To quote the docs,

> The `IServiceProvider` interface is implemented by a number of types, including `System.Web.HttpContext`, `System.ComponentModel.LicenseContext`, `System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent`, and `System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer`.

- `HttpContext` implements the interface, but the `GetService(Type)` method is documented as internal use only, and the only service it contains (in the public API, at least) is [`PageInstrumentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.pageinstrumentation(v=vs.110).aspx).  There is no way to query for all services in this implementation.
- [`ServiceContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.servicecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't actually implement the interface (though it does have an [internal field](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/design/ServiceObjectContainer.cs,45cdafacef2fe4bc,references) of that interface type.)  Even though the `ServiceContainer` doesn't implement the interface, it
  does implement the method, and [it's a bit scary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/design/ServiceObjectContainer.cs,6c82b616f5c5abad,references).  It does confirm suspicions - it's a glorified dictionary mapping types to services.  Again, this implementation doesn't provide its own way of getting all services it holds.  This is the one I expected to, since it's explicitly a container of services.
- `LicenseContext.GetService(Type)` [just returns null unless its overridden.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/LicenseContext.cs,08db7c21428dcb6d)  Perhaps some of this class' subclasses provide a way to get all services, but this one doesn't.

I'm done digging through source and docs.  It appears a bit messy, but the short answer above holds: old name or new, pseudoimplementation or actual implementation: there is no way to get all services from the `IServiceProvider` interface alone, and none of Microsoft's implementations that I found give you a way to do that either.

Answer (score 15):

There might be a simple solution if you are using Core Web Application. Here's what I ended up doing.

In Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton(services);
    }
```

This way you can inject the IServiceCollection to any class that needs it.

Comment: It doesn't answer to the question IMHO. How do you list all the registered services?

Answer (score 9):

Because this is still one of the top suggestions from google:

There is now a nuget extension set that you can pull down from M$ that extends the service provider and exposes several useful endpoints, one of those is "GetServices" which returns an IEnumerable based on the type you provide

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/

Answer (score 8):

For my Application I want to migrate all my `DbContexts` at once. So after the `IServiceCollection` is configured and an `IServiceProvider` is built, I don't got the chance to access them via `IServiceProvider`.

The following code snippet will do it, **BUT:**

**It is very experiemental, therefore a `UnitTest` should be implemented to note a change from Microsoft and adapt the method accordingly!**

```cs
public static class IServiceProviderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all registered <see cref="ServiceDescriptor"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="provider"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<Type, ServiceDescriptor> GetAllServiceDescriptors(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        if (provider is ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<Type, ServiceDescriptor>();

            var engine = serviceProvider.GetFieldValue("_engine");
            var callSiteFactory = engine.GetPropertyValue("CallSiteFactory");
            var descriptorLookup = callSiteFactory.GetFieldValue("_descriptorLookup");
            if (descriptorLookup is IDictionary dictionary)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
                {
                    result.Add((Type)entry.Key, (ServiceDescriptor)entry.Value.GetPropertyValue("Last"));
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Type '{provider.GetType()}' is not supported!");
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    // ##########################################################################################
    // Get / Set Field
    // ##########################################################################################

    #region Get / Set Field

    public static object GetFieldValue(this object obj, string fieldName)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        var fieldInfo = GetFieldInfo(objType, fieldName);
        if (fieldInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(fieldName,
                $"Couldn't find field {fieldName} in type {objType.FullName}");
        return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
    }

    public static void SetFieldValue(this object obj, string fieldName, object val)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        var fieldInfo = GetFieldInfo(objType, fieldName);
        if (fieldInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(fieldName,
                $"Couldn't find field {fieldName} in type {objType.FullName}");
        fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, val);
    }

    private static FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = null;
        do
        {
            fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            type = type.BaseType;
        } while (fieldInfo == null && type != null);

        return fieldInfo;
    }

    #endregion

    // ##########################################################################################
    // Get / Set Property
    // ##########################################################################################

    #region Get / Set Property

    public static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(objType, propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(propertyName,
                $"Couldn't find property {propertyName} in type {objType.FullName}");
        return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propertyName, object val)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(objType, propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(propertyName,
                $"Couldn't find property {propertyName} in type {objType.FullName}");
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, val, null);
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
        do
        {
            propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            type = type.BaseType;
        } while (propertyInfo == null && type != null);

        return propertyInfo;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## example usage to get all `DbContext`

register all `DbContext`

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ProductionDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "ProductionDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddDbContext<ProductionArchiveDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "ProductionArchiveDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddDbContext<RecipeDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "RecipesDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddDbContext<SecurityDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "SecurityDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddDbContext<TranslationDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "TranslationDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddDbContext<AlarmsDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Directories.Data, "AlarmsDb.sqlite")}"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Get them from your `IServiceProvier`

```cs
var dbContexts = provider.GetAllServiceDescriptors().Where(d => d.Key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbContext))).ToList();
```

[image]

*Please feel free to extend this class or remark bugs*

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension method that will return all services compatible with the specified type:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T> (this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var site = typeof(ServiceProvider).GetProperty("CallSiteFactory", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(provider);
    var desc = site.GetType().GetField("_descriptors", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(site) as ServiceDescriptor[];
    return desc.Select(s => provider.GetRequiredService(s.ServiceType)).OfType<T>();
}
```

To get all the services, use `provider.GetAll<object>()`.

For better performance, consider caching the results of `GetProperty` and `GetField` reflections.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general solution to this problem, it is dependent on the implementation you are using if there is any method you could use to find the list of services.

Answer (score 0):

So this is on the IServiceCollection, not the IServiceProvider.

I add this to "startup".... so at least I know how my app was IoC configured.

But I find it very very useful for troubleshooting.

I got this to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
   
namespace MyCompany.Components.DiDebugging
    {
      [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
      public static class IocDebugging
    {
        public static ICollection<ServiceDescriptor> GenerateServiceDescriptors(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ICollection<ServiceDescriptor> returnItems = new List<ServiceDescriptor>(services);
            return returnItems;
        }

        public static string GenerateServiceDescriptorsString(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> sds = GenerateServiceDescriptors(services).AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(o => o.ServiceType.FullName);
            foreach (ServiceDescriptor sd in sds)
            {
                sb.Append($"(ServiceDescriptor):");
                sb.Append($"FullName='{sd.ServiceType.FullName}',");
                sb.Append($"Lifetime='{sd.Lifetime}',");
                sb.Append($"ImplementationType?.FullName='{sd.ImplementationType?.FullName}'");
                sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            string returnValue = sb.ToString();
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static string GeneratePossibleDuplicatesServiceDescriptorsString(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            ICollection<DuplicateIocRegistrationHolder> foundDuplicates =
                (from t in GenerateServiceDescriptors(services)
                    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.ServiceType.FullName)
                          && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.ImplementationType?.FullName)
                    group t by new
                    {
                        ServiceTypeFullName = t.ServiceType.FullName, t.Lifetime,
                        ImplementationTypeFullName = t.ImplementationType?.FullName
                    }
                    into grp
                    where grp.Count() > 1
                    select new DuplicateIocRegistrationHolder()
                    {
                        ServiceTypeFullName = grp.Key.ServiceTypeFullName,
                        Lifetime = grp.Key.Lifetime,
                        ImplementationTypeFullName = grp.Key.ImplementationTypeFullName,
                        DuplicateCount = grp.Count()
                    }).ToList();

            foreach (DuplicateIocRegistrationHolder sd in foundDuplicates
                         .OrderBy(o => o.ServiceTypeFullName))
            {
                sb.Append($"(DuplicateIocRegistrationHolderServiceDescriptor):");
                sb.Append($"ServiceTypeFullName='{sd.ServiceTypeFullName}',");
                sb.Append($"Lifetime='{sd.Lifetime}',");
                sb.Append($"ImplementationTypeFullName='{sd.ImplementationTypeFullName}',");
                sb.Append($"DuplicateCount='{sd.DuplicateCount}'");
                sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            string returnValue = sb.ToString();
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static void LogServiceDescriptors<T>(this IServiceCollection services, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            string iocDebugging = services.GenerateServiceDescriptorsString();
            Func<object, Exception, string> logMsgStringFunc = (a, b) => iocDebugging;
            ILogger<T> logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
            logger.Log(
                LogLevel.Information,
                ushort.MaxValue,
                string.Empty,
                null,
                logMsgStringFunc);
            Console.WriteLine(iocDebugging);

            string iocPossibleDuplicates = GeneratePossibleDuplicatesServiceDescriptorsString(services);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iocPossibleDuplicates))
            {
                Func<object, Exception, string> logMsgStringDuplicatesFunc = (a, b) => iocPossibleDuplicates;
                logger.Log(
                    LogLevel.Warning,
                    ushort.MaxValue,
                    string.Empty,
                    null,
                    logMsgStringDuplicatesFunc);
                Console.WriteLine(iocPossibleDuplicates);
            }
        }

        [DebuggerDisplay("ServiceTypeFullName='{ServiceTypeFullName}', Lifetime='{Lifetime}', ImplementationTypeFullName='{ImplementationTypeFullName}', DuplicateCount='{DuplicateCount}'")]
        private sealed class DuplicateIocRegistrationHolder
        {
            public string ServiceTypeFullName { get; set; }

            public ServiceLifetime Lifetime { get; set; }

            public string ImplementationTypeFullName { get; set; }

            public int DuplicateCount { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and

and I call it in my Startup.cs

example usage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyCompany.Components.DiDebugging;


namespace MyCompany.MyApplicationOne
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
            this.LogFactory = logFactory;
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public ILoggerFactory LogFactory { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

                  /* wire up all your dependencies */
            services.AddScoped<IMyThing, MyThingConcrete>();
            
            
            /* the below must be LAST after all other IoC registrations */
            services.LogServiceDescriptors<Startup>(this.LogFactory);
        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little bit late, but I also needed the functionality to see whether a service was registered or not. Below my solution. I know it is not optional, but is fine for me.

I have made two extension methods for `IServiceProvider`:

```
public static class DiExtension
{
    private static IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;

    public static void AddServiceCollection(this IServiceProvider services, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
    }

    public static bool HasService(this IServiceProvider services, Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceCollection.Any(s => s.ServiceType.FullName == serviceType.FullName);
    }
}
```

As you can see is this the place where I keep a reference to `IServiceCollection` by invoking the `AddServiceCollection` method. This method is called in `Startup.cs` in the `Configure` method like this:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Domain.Logging.ILogger logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Notice that I inject IServiceProvider into the method
    serviceProvider.AddServiceCollection(_serviceCollection);
}
```

To get a reference to `IServiceCollection`, I set this in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // register all the things you need      

    _serviceCollection = services;
}
```

And offcourse `_serviceCollection`  is a private field in Startup.cs:

`private IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;`

Now, when everything is set, I can check whether a service is registered by using:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SomeClass(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(Type service)
    {
        var hasType = _serviceProvider.HasService(service);

        // Do what you have to do...
    }
}
```

Comment: @DominicJonas Man, this is very bad solution. It will call service constructor.