# How to get the list of injected services to a controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get the list of all injected services of a specific type to a controller in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as dependency injection container. I tried GetServices but it does not work.

```
serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IGenericRepository<,,>)).ToList()
```

serviceProvider is one of the services injected to the controller (IServiceProvider). As a test case,  I can get one service using the following line of code (below), but I can't get the list of  services.

```
IGenericRepository<CASES_BY_SUBTYPE, int, int> _CaseSubType = _serviceProvider.GetService<IGenericRepository<CASES_BY_SUBTYPE, int, int>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no build-in method could get all the service by using service provider, the GetServices method is just return a single service. If you still want to get all the services, you should build it by yourself.

I suggest you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60529530/7609093) to know how to build it. The replier get the codes from asp.net core unit test source codes.