# Compile-time DI Container with ASP.Net Core apps

Tags: asp.net-core, compile-time, iserviceprovider

I'm the author of a compile-time Dependency Injection (DI) container based on Roslyn Source Generator ([MrMeeseeks.DIE](https://github.com/Yeah69/MrMeeseeks.DIE)).

The container is easily applicable to console projects, libraries and UI apps like WPF, because they usually have natural root types which can be determined at compile-time (e.g. `Program` or `App`) and they are completely agnostic to DI containers (or let's say "service providers").

However, this doesn't seem to be the case for ASP.Net Core. It looks like it heavily relies on the `IServiceProvider` interface with its single function `public object? GetService (Type serviceType);` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider.getservice?view=net-7.0#system-iserviceprovider-getservice(system-type))). The issue with that while considering compile-time DI containers is that the function depends on a `Type` parameter which technically can only be known in runtime. Runtime comes of course after compile-time and therefore is too late for the container to adjust appropriately.

A possible solution that I have in mind is to generate an implementation of `IServiceProvider` which uses the compile-time DI container. However, for it to work the the types which the `GetService` function will be called with need to be collectable on compile-time.

Long story short: Given an arbitrary ASP.Net Core app, how can the list of all types, which can be possibly passed to `GetService` in an arbitrary app run, be determined comprehensively and automatically at compile-time?

Part of the answer probably are:

- Types deriving from `ControllerBase` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0))
- Types of parameters and properties marked with the `FromServicesAttributes` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0))

I have only little experience with ASP.Net Core yet, so I don't feel confident to compose a complete list of such types. So I'm asking for help here.

Comment: `how can the list of all types` --> per my searching, we don't have such a out-of-box method to get all the types. And this looks like a [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#recommendations) option. **Avoid using the service locator pattern. For example, don't invoke GetService to obtain a service instance when you can use DI instead**

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73086184/18391068

Comment: IServiceContainer extends IServiceProvider, which provides a container for all registered services. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.iservicecontainer?view=net-7.0

Comment: @TinyWang You are absolutely right about avoiding the service locator pattern. But that wasn't what I was talking about.

My question is about the `GetService` calls which the ASP.Net Core Framework itself does behind the scenes, not about `GetService` calls that the concrete app's codebase does. I wouldn't recommend the latter either.

If your ASP.Net Core app uses Controllers, then I'm sure it'll be instantiated by the ASP.Net Core framework via the `IServiceProvider` interface. Aggregating the types of such calls is what this question is about.

Comment: Hi per my searching, there's no such out-of-box method, you might go to github to check the source code...

Comment: @EmreBener Thank you. Both hints are definitely worth getting a closer look into. One thing that cross my mind. Ideally it shouldn't be a list of all service types, but it should be narrowed down to the services that the `GetService` function will be called with (which are most likely far less from all service types). The reason is that the compile-time DI-container would generate some code for each of the types of the aggregated list and a lot of it would be redundant. But I'll investigate in these option as soon as I have free time.

Comment: @TinyWang Good point. Thanks. I recently tried cloning the ASP.Net Core repo and opening it in the IDE. The idea was to go through the usages of `GetService`. The IDE crashed. I think, I'll try harder or maybe make a full text search without IDE and its indexing.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, and you might also try to open a issue ticket in asp.net core github to ask if there's such kind of method...